# Share private video to some google accounts through API

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to figure out wheter it is possible to have a private video on youtube that I could share with particular Google Accounts through API.

I would have a separate web application that would have a Google signup and after signup I would enable that Google Account to watch my private video.

Ideally I would also want to embed the video to the web application (but I think I can do this rather easily if I'm an owner of the video).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ispossible to have a private video on YouTube that I could share with particular google accounts through API.

No you cant directly share a video with another user like you could a file on google drive.

You could show the video on your own site, but I am not sure its something I would want to try.   The thing is being that its a private video you and you alone have access to see it.   Your going to have to authenticate your application and get a refresh token back which will allow you to access the account and the videos on the account.

Then you will be able to use that refresh token to get an access token to show other people the video via your website.   The problem you will have is if the refresh token stops working (rarely happens but can happen) you will have to authenticate it again before your solution will work.

*Note: Service accounts don't work with YouTube API. So don't bother going down that road.*

Comment: OK, do you then have an idea how I could programmatically give access to some videos on youtube after a certain authentication process (after payment for example). I could just have it all in my own web application, but I'd like to have youtube storing those videos.

Comment: You can not. You cant grant someone else permission to one of your Videos.

Comment: @DalmTo actually, you can. When you set a video to private, you can invite people (=other Google accounts) to see that video. Access is restricted to the specified accounts, so other people who know the ID still can't watch the video. AFAIK this is only doable through the YouTube website though, not through the API.

Comment: @paolo is correct. You can share a private video on YouTube website using old studio interface, not through the API.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the ID of a video, you can access it. You can share the ID,or an embedded link with someone.

The api only hides the info, not blocks it. So you would need to hold the info elsewhere for referencing.

So as long as you know the id's of the related video's, you can do what you want with them.

However, if you are wanting to monetise them on the side, I would recommend against it.  Best to read the user agreement you have with YouTube.

Comment: I don't think this will work with a video which has been set to private.   Even adding an access token will probably not work.

Comment: Good to know, I think I will exclude youtube from this completely.

Comment: @DaImTo . Can you see this embed? https://www.youtube.com/embed/7iqhi_s0DRE?rel=0 This is a private video I made that I use for my sites as a place holder. no api key needed to see it. Just the ID

Comment: @Tempus. https://www.youtube.com/embed/7iqhi_s0DRE?rel=0 this video is not private.

Comment: @PankajShinde . It was a long time ago that I set that video up. And it was set to private so as to be hidden and not be seen on my channel normally. It is currently marked as "Unlisted". So still relevant.