# How give user premissions to watch private video using youtube api?

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

I need to add user email addres to permitted users list for private video. How I can do it using youtube api?
Manual use: https://youtu.be/fcJJsX_6CFw?t=32

Comment: possible duplicate of- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926332/share-private-video-to-some-google-accounts-through-api

Answer (score 0):

Make the video UNLISTED instead of PRIVATE.

Comment: If I make video unlisted, users can share link and non-premitted users can watch it. But I need that only users from permitted list can watch video.